# adding a whole /28 block into network

Tags: networking, interface, routing

I currently have the following netowrking config:

```
auto p2p1:0
iface p2p1:0 inet static
        address 104.144.1.65
        netmask 255.255.255.240


auto p2p1:2
iface p2p1:2 inet static
        address 104.144.1.67
        netmask 255.255.255.240


.............

auto p2p1:16
iface p2p1:16 inet static
        address 104.144.1.81
        netmask 255.255.255.240
```

While all that I want to do is assign the whole 104.144.1.65/28 to this network interface ? Is there a shortcut to say the following:

```
auto p2p1:0
iface p2p1:0 inet static
        address 104.144.1.65/28
        netmask 255.255.255.240
```

so that I don't have to type in all the 16 IP one by one

Answer (score 0):

You can put into your config file ip route commands like this :

```
for i in $(seq 64 78) ;do echo up ip addr add 104.144.1.$i/28 dev p2p1:0 ;done
```

Just paste the output below "iface p2p1:0 inet static" and that's done :)

Comment: Great idea ! But that is not permanent, and I think that is what is looked for here. Maybe you can expand on your approach ?

Comment: Of course it is (permanent) ! I have added the "up" prefix to put the command at start of the /etc/network/interfaces files. That mean to be used by network init script to alias ip to interface.... :)
You can also copy/paste the "ip addr add...." part to see the result in non-permanent mode

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with this syntax in `interfaces` .  This `up ip addr add` looked like `ifconfig` syntax . If its for the `interfaces` file, why not redirect the output there instead of copy/pasteing all those lines ?

Comment: okay I did so me digging. Its not the corretc ifconfig syntax, but behind the `up` you can write anything, it basically amounts to the execution of scripts located in `/etc/network/if-up.d/` - that means, however, you cannot use `ifconfig` anymore, since it doesn't know about it. Also, the naming of interfaces does not work, all interfaces will be `secondary p2p1` instead of `secondary p2p1:<number>`.